# AngularJS error - [$compile:multidir] Multiple directives error

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I use these packages:
An angularjs modal from angular-ui package: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal
And Angular-flexslider from here: https://github.com/EnthusiasticCode/angular-flexslider

Every plugin works good when they are in separate pages. but when i use them in one page, angular-flexslider causes an error:

```
Error: [$compile:multidir] Multiple directives [flexSlider, slide] asking for transclusion on: <div class="flexslider-container ng-isolate-scope ng-scope" slide="s in slides" animation="slide">
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.2/$compile/multidir?p0=flexSlider&p1=s…20ng-scope%22%20slide%3D%22s%20in%20slides%22%20animation%3D%22slide%22%3E
    at ...
```

The template file is this:

```
<flex-slider slide="s in slides" animation="slide">
    <li>
        <img ng-src="{{s}}">
    </li>
</flex-slider>

<div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
        <h3>I'm a modal!</h3>
    </script>

    <button class="btn" ng-click="open()">Open me!</button>
</div>
```

And app.js file:

```
angular.module('theApp', ['theApp.filters', 'theApp.services', 'theApp.directives', 'theApp.controllers', 'ngRoute', 'ngSanitize', 'angular-flexslider', 'ui.bootstrap']).
  config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/home', {templateUrl: (someurl...) , controller: (a name ...) });
  }]);
```

The controller.js file is:

```
angular.module('theApp.controllers', [])
 .controller('SliderMedium', [ '$scope', function($scope) {
   $scope.slides = [
     'images/slider/01.png',
     'images/slider/02.png',
   ];
 }]);

// ========= THIS IS controllers from angular-ui with no modification =======:
// ==========================================================================
var ModalDemoCtrl = function ($scope, $modal) {

  $scope.items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];

  $scope.open = function () {

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
      resolve: {
        items: function () {
          return $scope.items;
        }
      }
    });
  };
};

var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, items) {

  $scope.items = items;
  $scope.selected = {
    item: $scope.items[0]
  };

  $scope.ok = function () {
    $modalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
  };

  $scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
};
```

How can i fix it?  Tell me if further information is needed. Thanks.

**UPDATE:** unnecessary html markups removed, controller.js and app.js contents added.

Comment: Sorry but i don't see where you use flexSlider & slide directives ? This is all your templates or is it incomplete ?

Comment: @ThomasPons sorry for that. question updated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A directive named `slide` looks to be both in `angular-flexslider` and `ui.bootstrap.carousel`. If you don't need carousel, try making a build of AngularUI Bootstrap without carousel support.

It looks like angular is using the boostrap `slide` instead of the flexslider `slide` and the bootstrap one requires transclusion which is also required by `flex-slider`, so there's a conflict as to which one gets precedence.

You may also be able to fix this by fiddling with the load order, but I'm not certain of that.

Comment: The documentation now specifies to use "flex-slide" as the directive in conjunction with bootstrap UI (github.com/thenikso/angular-flexslider#usage) See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23475821/how-to-use-flexslider-or-parallax-slider-with-angularjs-with-angular-ui

Answer (score 5):

To avoid conflict with bootstrap carousel thenikso/angular-flexslider added a new directive `flex-slide` along with `slide`.

Bootstrap users can use `flex-slide` instead of `slide` directive.

```
<flex-slider flex-slide="s in slides" animation="slide">
    <li>
        <img ng-src="{{s}}">
    </li>
</flex-slider>
```

Answer (score 3):

Jussi Kosunen has right, but you don't need to make your own build of AngularUI Bootstrap.
Just rename slide to fslide in your HTML.

```
<flex-slider slide="s in slides" animation="slide">
    <li>
        <img ng-src="{{s}}">
    </li>
</flex-slider>
```

to

```
<flex-slider fslide="s in slides" animation="slide">
        <li>
            <img ng-src="{{s}}">
        </li>
</flex-slider>
```

And of course the directive in angular-flexslider.js.

```
match = attr.slide.match(/^\s*(.+)\s+in\s+(.*?)(?:\s+track\s+by\s+(.+?))?\s*$/);
```

to

```
match = attr.fslide.match(/^\s*(.+)\s+in\s+(.*?)(?:\s+track\s+by\s+(.+?))?\s*$/);
```

And don't forget to leave that steps in Readme file for other contributors.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error..because I copied a pre-made directive to make a new directive...and forgot to change the directive name.
`.directive('addTransaction', function () {`

Comment: Can you add context as to how this helps the OP?