# how to use Flexslider or parallax slider with AngularJS (with Angular UI)?

Tags: angularjs, flexslider, angular-ui-bootstrap

Have anybody tried using [Flexslider](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/) and [Parallax-Slider](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/03/15/parallax-content-slider-with-css3-and-jquery/) in AngularJS application?
None of them works if I use them in AngularJS application.
This AngularJS application is also using UI Bootstrap.
Any advice or suggestion is welcome.

Comment: The Sliders. It just show the backgorund image and Prev and Next arrows.None of the slides get displayed.

Answer (score 0):

have you looked at https://github.com/EnthusiasticCode/angular-flexslider or https://github.com/durated/angular-parallax which help use them in Angular.

Comment: angular-flexslider does not work if you use them with Ui-Bootstrap.Because both uses Slide directive it throws exception. I am yet to try angular-parallax.

Comment: The documentation now specifies to use "flex-slide" as the directive in conjunction with bootstrap UI (https://github.com/thenikso/angular-flexslider#usage)